# Get only the logged user's records in play framework

Tags: playframework

I must have missed this somehow...

In my app user "x" owns posts 1, 4, 8. He should only be able to view/edit those.
If I open `localhost:9000/post/1` in the browser I expect it to sow details with the ability to edit.

When I open `localhost:9000/post/99` - he should not be able to view or edit this post. How can I restrict that in Play Framework?

I am aware of the [@Check](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/secure) concept but is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way you need to hit the database to see whether a user is allowed to see a Post.

You can put this code in the @Before interceptor for that controller or in the relevant show method which pulls the Post record - and if not authorized, call forbidden() method.

Comment: Thanks! Would prefer to combine your answer with Seb's (below)... I like the idea of doing it once in the controller but that means that I would have to run two queries every time any method gets ran in the controller? Maybe that's what has to happen in order to keep clean code.

Comment: Instead of hitting the db every time, you can Cache a map of Postids and userids. Validate against this. This way performance improves.

Answer (score 1):

The standard secure module does not allow that level of granularity.

I had a similar requirement and I used the [secure permissions](http://www.playframework.org/modules/securepermissions) module, based on drools.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but the module seems to be dead and not quite compatible with the latest play?

Comment: Yeah the module page is not up to date but the [github project](https://github.com/lunatech-labs/play-module-permissions) is up to date with 1.2.4. Was made by lunatech, the main company behind the playframework

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is to store the connected user's id in the session and when you find your post in the database you search by post id AND user id instead of just post id. This way you won't find the post 99 for your user.